# No Validation in Modal Partial View Asp .Net Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core

I use Modal and Load Partial view to it, but if I keep fields blank no validation happened and modal closed after click submit button.

Also I use Required annotation in my viewmodel. Also when I click submit it calls action direct in controller.

My Question: how can I display a validation message in modal form?

```js
@section scripts{
    <script>
        function onFailureDefault(data) {
           
            $("#AddOrderDetailModalDiv").valid()
        }
        function OpenAddOrderDetailTempItemOnSuccess() {
            $("#AddOrderDetailModalDiv").modal("show");
        }

        function AddOrderDetailTempItemOnComplete() {
            $("#AddOrderDetailModalDiv").modal("hide");
        }
        
    </script>
}
```

```html
@model OrderDetailViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrderDetailTempItem", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new
{
    id = "AddForm",
    @data_ajax = "true",
    @data_ajax_method = "post",
    @data_ajax_update = "#OrderDetailList",
    @data_ajax_failure = "onFailureDefault",

    @data_ajax_complete = "AddOrderDetailTempItemOnComplete"
}))
{
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-warning white">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">@( Model.ID > 0 ? "Edit Product" : "Add Product" )</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ProductId" class="control-label"></label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductId, Model.ProductsList, " ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "select2 form-control" })
                            <span asp-validation-for="ProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
                            

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Quantity" required class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Unit" class="control-label"></label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Unit, Model.QuantityUnitsList, " ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            <span asp-validation-for="Unit" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="UnitPrice" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="UnitPrice" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label id="ErrorMessage" asp-for="ErrorMessage" class="form-control" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Product" id="postSave" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrderDetailTempItem(OrderDetailViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        List<OrderDetailViewModel> models = OrderDetailViewModelList;
        var product = productService.SingleBy(model.ProductId);
        if (model.ID > 0)
        {
            var updatedItem = models.Find(m => m.ID == model.ID);
            updatedItem.Quantity = model.Quantity;
            updatedItem.ProductId = model.ProductId;
            updatedItem.UnitPrice = model.UnitPrice;
            updatedItem.TotalPrice = model.Quantity * model.UnitPrice;
            updatedItem.ProductName = product.Name;
            updatedItem.Unit = model.Unit;
            updatedItem.QuantityUnitsText = ((QuantityUnits)model.Unit).ToString();
            updatedItem.isActive = true;
            //mapper.Map(model,updatedItem);///

        }
        else
        {
            models.Add(new OrderDetailViewModel
            {
                ID = counter - 1,//models.Count + 1,
                Quantity = model.Quantity,
                ProductId = model.ProductId,
                UnitPrice = model.UnitPrice,
                TotalPrice = model.Quantity * model.UnitPrice,
                ProductName = product.Name,
                Unit = model.Unit,
                QuantityUnitsText = ((QuantityUnits)model.Unit).ToString(),
                isActive = true,
            });
            counter -= 1;
        }
        OrderDetailViewModelList = models;
        return PartialView("_OrderDetailGridPartial", OrderDetailViewModelList.Where(a => a.isActive == true).ToList());
    }
```

Parent View

```
                                        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrder", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new
                                    {
                                        id = "AddForm",
                                        @data_ajax = "true",
                                        @data_ajax_method = "post",
                                        //@data_ajax_update = "#OrderDetailList",

                                        @data_ajax_complete = "AddOrderOnComplete"
                                    }))
                                    {
                                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label asp-for="DeliveryDate" class="control-label"></label>
                                                    <input asp-for="DeliveryDate" class="form-control" type="date" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label asp-for="OrderDate" class="control-label"></label>
                                                    <input asp-for="OrderDate" class="form-control" disabled type="date" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="OrderDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label asp-for="CustomerId" class="control-label"></label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerId, Model.CustomersList, "Please select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "select2 form-control" })
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label asp-for="Notes" class="control-label"></label>
                                                    <textarea asp-for="Notes" rows="4" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="Notes" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>


                                        <div class="content-header row">
                                            <div class="content-header-left col-md-9 col-12 mb-2">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="content-header-right text-md-right col-md-3 col-12">
                                                <div class="form-group breadcrum-right">


                                                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-gradient-danger mr-1 mb-1 waves-effect waves-light">
                                                        <i class="feather icon-package">
                                                            @Html.ActionLink("Add Product", "AddOrderDetailTempItem", "Orders", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new
                                                       {
                                                           Style = "color:White;font-family:'Montserrat';padding-left: 10px;",
                                                           @data_ajax = "true",
                                                           @data_ajax_method = "Get",
                                                           @data_ajax_update = "#AddOrderDetailModalDiv",
                                                           @data_ajax_failure = "onFailureDefault",
                                                           @data_ajax_success = "OpenAddOrderDetailTempItemOnSuccess",
                                                       })
                                                        </i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <div id="OrderDetailList">
                                            <partial name="_OrderDetailGridPartial.cshtml" model="Model.OrderDetailViewModel" />
                                        </div>







                                        <div class="form-group  col-sm-3">
                                            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                        </div>
                                    }
```

My Model

```
  public class OrderDetailViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "حقل إجباري")]

    [Display(Name ="Product Name")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "حقل إجباري")]

    public int Unit { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "حقل إجباري")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "حقل إجباري")]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public SelectList ProductsList { get; set; }
    public SelectList QuantityUnitsList { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public string QuantityUnitsText { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Model?  Have you used DataAnnotaions on your model?

Comment: Yes I Used Required DataAnnotaions in my model also I update question to include model

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete，so I provide a work demo,you can check it.

**Model:**

```
  public class Student
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**_OrderDetailGridPartial:**

```
@model Student

<div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <h4 class="modal-title" >Update Role</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="myform" method="post">
                    <div>
                        <label>Id</label>
                        <input asp-for="Id" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button id="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Index View:**

```
<button id="showmodal" class="btn btn-danger">
Click
</button>
<div id="partical">
    <partial name="~/Views/Shared/_OrderDetailGridPartial.cshtml" />
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $("#showmodal").click(function () {
            $('#MyModal').modal('show');
        })
        $("#button").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var model = $('#myform').serialize();
            console.log(model);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'home/index',
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                data: model,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#partical').html(result);
                    $('#MyModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

**Action:**

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
  

    [HttpPost]       
    public IActionResult Index(Student student)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView("_OrderDetailGridPartial",student);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Test result**

[image]

Comment: Hi @yinqiuThanks ,but my modal form inside parent form (I update my question) when I click submit inside Modal its call action method for parent form.